# JavaScript Readonly Attribute Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have in my code to make a field readOnly, however it just grays the field out and the field can still be edited. What am i doing wrong here ?

The fields I'm using in this are Django crispy fields on my form.

Code For The  Form

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
       {% csrf_token %} 
      <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-3">
          {{form.class_name|as_crispy_field }} 
          </div>
        <div class = "col-3">
          {{form.date|as_crispy_field }}
          </div>
        <div class = "col-3">
        {{form.week_of|as_crispy_field }}
          </div>
          <div class = "col-3">
             {{form.day|as_crispy_field }}
             </div>
       </div>
        <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-3">  
          {{form.student_name|as_crispy_field }} 
          </div>
         <div class = "col-3"> 
          {{form.time_frame|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class = "col-3">
        {{form.behavior|as_crispy_field }}
         </div>
         <div class="col-3" >
        {{form.academic|as_crispy_field }}
         </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
         <div class = "col-3">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ><i
                class="fas fa-star"></i> Level Up</button>
      </form>
                 </div>
                  </div>

</div>
```

```
    <script>
      const student_name = "{{student_id}}";
      var studentnamedropdown = document.getElementById('id_student_name');
      for (i = 0; i < studentnamedropdown.options.length; i++) {
      // if(studentnamedropdown.options[i].text == "Ray Zuchowski")
      if(studentnamedropdown.options[i].text == student_name)
      {
      console.log(studentnamedropdown.options[i].text)  
      $("#id_student_name").val(studentnamedropdown.options[i].value)
      $("#id_student_name").attr('readonly', 'readonly')

       }
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: "however it just grays the field out" okay so what is the issue?

Comment: Some browsers gray out "readonly" fields.  I think Firefox does, but Chrome does not. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly#Example

Comment: I can still edit the field. I dont want to be able to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Set readOnly with prop

```js
$("#test").prop("readOnly", true)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="x" id="test" />
```

Comment: I tried the prop method as well, the field will no longer be gray and still can be edited.

Comment: Well it works fine in the snipplet so not sure what is different.

Comment: Difference is im using a django form field and not reg html fields.

Comment: "and not reg html fields." well what are these fields? You need to specify these things when you ask questions.

Comment: Yeah that was my bad, i forgot to put that. I added it now.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some confusion with jQuery `.attr` and `.prop` going on here.

In plain JavaScript it would be

```
document.getElementById('id_student_name').readOnly = true
```

Comment: This work in my other scripts this way, using reg javascript. But not successful doing this in the current script posted.

Comment: That's very weird. That should absolutely work. You could check the output of `document.getElementById('id_student_name').readOnly` afterwards in the console. Maybe some other framework tampers with it?

Comment: What makes this different is these fields are relationship fields and they are dropdown. So i dont know if that makes a difference.